# Reading different bag files yeilds the same data

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the rosbag API to read from several pre-recorded bag files.  The bag files show themselves to be different in rxbag.  However, when I try to print a single data field (kinect skeleton left_hand x coordinate), the data is always the same for a given sample.  The code I'm using is below.  I'm using electric on ubuntu 10.4.

Thanks for any assistance.
Paul.

```
printf("File: %s, representation being generated. \n", bagFileName);

  gesture_bag.open(bagFileName, rosbag::bagmode::Read);
  double x = 0.0;

  rosbag::View view(gesture_bag, rosbag::TopicQuery("Skeletons"));

  BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view) {
    body_msgs::Skeletons::ConstPtr s = m.instantiate<body_msgs::Skeletons>();
    if (s != NULL) {
      x = s->skeletons[0].left_hand.position.x;
      printf("x = %f \n", x);
    }
  }
```

EDIT:

Adding an example program execution transcript for two bag files.  These bag files can be seen in their entirety at:  https://media.wcu.edu/groups/wcuee222studentwork.  (note - this is not course work.  just reusing a course website to post my bag files.).

```
Press <return> to begin collecting to Paul_1.bag.
File: Paul_1.bag, saved.
File: Paul_1.bag, representation being generated.
x = -0.165174
x = -0.169588
x = -0.169613
x = -0.169891
x = -0.170148
x = -0.170124
x = -0.169971
x = -0.169847
x = -0.169541
x = -0.169788
Press <return> to continue.

Press <return> to begin collecting to Paul_2.bag.
File: Paul_2.bag, saved.
File: Paul_2.bag, representation being generated.
x = -0.165174
x = -0.169588
x = -0.169613
x = -0.169891
x = -0.170148
x = -0.170124
x = -0.169971
x = -0.169847
x = -0.169541
x = -0.169788
Press <return> to continue.  ^C
```

Adding rosbag filter info for the same program execution:

```
^Mjunk.bag                                      0%   0.0 KB /  12.9 KB --:-- ETA MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060405.655579954: -0.16517427063
^Mjunk.bag                                      3%   0.5 KB /  12.9 KB 00:40 ETA MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060405.655769731: -0.169587921143
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060405.655794001: -0.169612945557
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060405.655817728: -0.16989100647
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060405.662843791: -0.170148040771
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060405.697162109: -0.170123809814
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060405.729331279: -0.169971343994
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060405.770241581: -0.16984703064
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060405.789512869: -0.16954119873
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060405.825295207: -0.169788131714
^Mjunk.bag                                    100%             12.9 KB 00:01
^Mjunk.bag                                      0%   0.0 KB /  12.9 KB --:-- ETA MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060409.990274185: -0.1686847229
^Mjunk.bag                                      3%   0.5 KB /  12.9 KB 00:42 ETA MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060409.990326913: -0.171818161011
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060409.990342712: -0.171740097046
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060409.990359413: -0.171201141357
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060410.29273650: -0.171574584961
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060410.59427515: -0.171567443848
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060410.96649801: -0.171443496704
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060410.133197640: -0.171264755249
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060410.162194287: -0.170930633545
MATCH Skeletons @ 1322060410.194114200: -0.171098449707
^Mjunk.bag                                    100%             12.9 KB 00:01
```

Adding source code showing generation of the bag files.  The program output repeatedly shows the contents of the first bag file generated despite the fact that the filename of a newly generated bag file is passed successfully to the bag read function.:

```
void gestureLrn::getJointsCallback_2(const body_msgs::Skeletons &skel) 
{
  static int numFrames = 0;
  static int bagFileNum = 0;
  static int desiredFrames = 10;
  static char fname[40];
  char participantName[20] = "Paul";


  if (numFrames == 0) {
    // Open a new ROS bag file on the first frame.
    bagFileNum++;
    sprintf(fname, "%s_%d.bag", participantName, bagFileNum);
    printf("Press <return> to begin collecting to %s.", fname);
    char b = getchar();
    gesture_bag.open(fname, rosbag::bagmode::Write);
  }

  if (numFrames < desiredFrames) {
    gesture_bag.write("Skeletons", ros::Time::now(), skel);
    numFrames++;
  }
  else {
    numFrames = 0;
    gesture_bag.close();
    printf("File: %s, saved. \n", fname);

    // Add representation generator here.
    genRep_dynamicInstants(fname);

    printf("Press <return> to continue. ");
    char k = getchar();
    printf("\n");
  }

} // end getJointsCallback_2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12049/reading-different-bag-files-yeilds-the-same-data/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-11-23**:
The link for the bags doesn't open for me.  Can you post the code of   genRep_dynamicInstants(fname) . Are you sure it is using the fname supplied?

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-11-22**:
Can you please share the bags somehow and some of your output as you run this? Also, can you show the definition of gesture_bag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Separating the declarations (rosbag::Bag gesture_bag  vs. rosbag::Bag read_bag) for read vs. write bags and moving the read bag declaration to the read function solved this problem.  Interestingly, moving the declaration for the write bag to the write function did not work.  That one had to remain in the class prototype.  Any explanation as to why either of these is true would be helpful.

Paul.

---

Originally posted by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) with karma: 271 on 2011-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0